# Why subscribe/unsubscribe button in the custom entity named group cannot appear?

Tags: 7, organic-groups, javascript

I have created a custom render in `group_module.js` exactly as the example [Rendering Entities](http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Entities/Rendering_Entities) with the exception of the line `items['group/%'] = {` instead of `items['team/%'] = {`. All other content nodes but group nodes (`group/%`) show ok. Group nodes show no subscribe/unsubscribe button and no menu tabs mentioned below in the `groups_menu_module.js`. I suppose that this module, `groups_menu_module.js`, is not loaded somehow.
I have to mention that without the custom rendering of entity group and with 2 LOCAL_TASK_MENU menu tabs, everything works perfect.

groups_menu_module.js

```
function groups_menu_module_menu() {
  try {
    var items = {};
    items['group/%']={
      title: 'view',
      page_callback: 'drupalgap_get_entity',
      page_arguments: ['groups_menu_module_default_page', 'node', 1]
    };
    items['group/%/provoli'] = {
      title: 'view',    
      type: 'MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK'
    };
    items['group/%/melh'] = {
      title: 'members',
      type: 'MENU_LOCAL_TASK',
      page_callback: 'groups_menu_module_melh_page',
      page_arguments: [1],
      title_callback: 'groups_menu_module_melh_page_title',
      title_arguments: [1],
      access_callback: 'groups_menu_module_page_access',
      access_arguments: [1],
      options: {
        reloadPage: true
      }
    };
    items['group/%/anarthseis'] = {
      title: 'posts',
      type: 'MENU_LOCAL_TASK',
      page_callback: 'groups_menu_module_anarthseis_page',
      page_arguments: [1],
      access_callback: 'groups_menu_module_page_access',
      access_arguments: [1],
      options: {
        reloadPage: true
      }
    };
    return items;
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log('groups_menu_module_menu - ' + error); 
  }
}

function groups_menu_module_default_page(node) {
  try {
    var content = {};
    content['title'] = { markup: node.title };
    return content;
  }
  catch (error) { 
    console.log('groups_menu_module_default_page - ' + error); 
  }
}
```

I have to mention that all functions needed are present in the actual .js file, i just opted them out because i think they are irrelevant.
The `pageshow` function of the other module is as the example in the above link:

group_module.js

```
function example_team_pageshow(nid) {
  node_load(nid, {
    success: function(node) {
      var content = node.title; // Add other content here...
      $('#' + example_team_container_id(nid)).html(content).trigger('create');
    }
  });
}
```

So to conclude the question is how to make the subscribe/unsubscribe button appear in the custom entity render? How to call og_ui_field_formatter_view() from my module to make the button appear?

I don't know if i made my self clear what is needed. If anyone need more information please ask so in the comments below to clarify some points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are taking over the display of Organic Groups nodes using your custom page callback path `group/%`, DrupalGap doesn't know to apply the field format view functions to your fields. Essentially you need to manually create/render your own widgets in your `page_callback`:

```
var content = {};
content.title = { /* ... */ };
content.subscribe = { /* ... */ };
return content;
```

There are helper functions in the `og.js` file related to joining/leaving groups that will be of help. From there just use simple HTML/CSS/JS to build your button(s) (perhaps with an `onclick` handler) to help the user interact with the group subscriptions.

If you want to call the `og_ui_field_formatter_view()` function directly (not recommended) you can, you just need to pass it all the correct parameters:

`(entity_type, entity, field, instance, langcode, items, display)`

- the `entity_type` is typically `'node'`
- the `entity` will be the fully loaded JSON of the entity (already delivered to your `page_callback`)
- the `field` and `instance` can be retrieved from http://api.drupalgap.org/7/global.html#drupalgap_field_info_field and http://api.drupalgap.org/7/global.html#drupalgap_field_info_instance respectively.
- the `langcode` will most likely be `und` unless you are using a multi-lingual site
- the `items` will be the value(s) within the field itself
- the `display` you should default to `{ type: 'og_group_subscribe' }`.

Not the easiest things to do to be honest, and you'll probably find yourself happier in the long run by building your own custom widget to subscribe/unsubscribe from the Group.

Feel free to copy any code you need from the `og.js` file to make your life easier.

Comment: @tyler-frankestein So there is no other way of calling `og_ui_field_formatter_view()` from my module or altering the onclick handler? Of what i understand, what you suggest is making the button from scratch?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include details about calling the function directly, but as you noticed, I'd really recommend just building the widget from scratch, that way you have complete control over it.